# Cakephp Newbie Model question

Tags: cakephp, model

I have a table familiars , a table mages and a table mages_familiars where I keep which familiar belongs to which Mage.

How can I model this cross reference table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read the manual? There's an [entire section](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together) devoted to this. What have you tried?

Comment: I can't find where it says about cross reference tables

Comment: That's because you don't need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the intermediary table unless it's possible that a familiar can belong to multiple mages and mages can have multiple familiars (a [HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM) relationship). In that case the table should have fields `id` (int), `created` (datetime), `modified` (datetime), `mage_id` (int) and `familiar_id` (int). Also, the table should be named `familiars_mages`.

If a familiar can belong to only one mage, a familiar [belongsTo](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1042/belongsTo) a mage and a mage [hasMany](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1043/hasMany) familiars. The familiars table should have a `mage_id` field.

If a familiar can belong to only one mage, and a mage can have only one familiar, you can use a [hasOne](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1041/hasOne) relationship. In that case either the mages table has a `familiar_id` field or the familiars table has a `mage_id` field.

Comment: So I need a cross reference table only when there is a HABTM relationship?

Comment: Right. If you read the documentation on each of the relationships, and they don't mention a reference table, then you don't need one.